# How to config maven pom.xml when my don't want src/test/java present in my eclipse java build path source category when update project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, buildpath

I don't need src/test/java folder in my maven project, so I delete it. But when I update the project in eclipse, I checked the build path, it shows that the src/test/java source folder is missing. I wonder how to configure the pom is solve this issue?

Comment: what happens when you try and build the project from command line `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Nothing unnormal happens when run the mvn command. The error only occurs in the eclipse. It is caused by the maven eclipse plugin, which is used to generate the eclipse .classpath and .project file. Usually it will generate the .classpath file with the `src/test/java` entry, I don't want it to generate the `src/test/java` entry, just the `src/main/java` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Your POM is incorrect. In that, you are specifying Maven to look for java class files in `src/test/java`.

If your java code is under a different folder, you can specify that folder in `sourceDirectory` tag in the POM.

If you don't have any java code and maybe you are simply building some non-java project with some resources, you can change your POM `build` tag to something like following:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>some/directory</directory>
            <targetPath>some/target</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: I have java classes in `src/main/java` folder, I have no test classes, so I delete `src/test/java` folder. But when I update the project in eclipse, there will be an error in the source part of the build path. What I want is to avoid this error after update of the project. I can easily delete the entry in the build path, but it is only a temp solution, when I update the project, the error will persist again. So I am looking for a solution in the pom.xml file.